# Is Model 1 a subcategory of the MVC architecture?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

A simple question asked many many many many times...

Model 1 and Model 2 Architecture...

I simple cannot uderstand why Model one is called MVC1...

Cause in the Model 1 we don't have that strong decoupling from Model view and controllor, in Model 1, a request is made to a JSP or servlet and then that JSP or servlet handles all responsibilities for the request...

So if the sepration from the controller and the view is not an evidence, why call the Model 1, simply a subcategry of the MVC pattern?

It's just the start of the historical process that brings us to the MVC achitecture..

Is my reasoning right?

This article:

http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/1012/developing_mvc_applications/adf_aboutmvc2.html

Seems to agree with me...but i would like to know what you think about...

Comment: Both of your answers have clarified my question... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java BluePrints 4.4.1 Structuring the Web Tier specifically warn against this interpretation:

> The literature on Web-tier technology in the J2EE platform frequently
>   uses the terms "Model 1" and "Model 2" without explanation. This
>   terminology stems from early drafts of the JSP specification, which
>   described two basic usage patterns for JSP pages. While the terms have
>   disappeared from the specification document, they remain in common
>   use. Model 1 and Model 2 simply refer to the absence or presence
>   (respectively) of a controller servlet that dispatches requests from
>   the client tier and selects views.

Moreover, if we consider that the **Model–view–controller (MVC) architectural pattern** goal is to *divide* the application into three interconnected parts (*Model*, *View* and *Controller*) and that the **Model 1** has no separation between *Controller* and *View*, I don't know if Model 1 can be considered a subcategory of the MVC.

**Model 2**, instead, is usually associated with the Model–view–controller (MVC) paradigm, as it drives a separation between logic and display.

Answer (score 1):

If you read MVC wiki - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller -  you will see there is no concept of MVC Model 1 OR MVC1 pattern OR MVC Model 2 OR MVC2, only the concept of the MVC pattern.

When you develop JSP application. For simple applications, you can use way 1 (Article call Model 1) that JSP page not only contains the display elements to output HTML, but is also responsible for extracting HTTP request parameters, call the business logic (implemented in JavaBeans, if not directly in the JSP), and handle the HTTP session. Way 1 is not implement MVC pattern because all in JSP page, no decouping.

For complex application, you can use way 2 that IMPLEMENT MVC pattern ( Article call MVC - Model 2 - This name has word is MVC because Model 2 implement MVC pattern). Way 2 ( MVC implementation) help us decouping between View and business logic processing (Controller), between view and model.